# Unexpected end of input JSON.parse (PHP, JSON, jQuery.post, database)

Tags: php, json, jquery-post

I have a php-file which creates a json and passes it on to javascript

```
<?php
    $index = 0;
    $connection = mysql_connect(*secret*,*secret*,*secret*);
    mysql_select_db("sql7150348");
    $query =mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  statements");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        $array[$index] = $row;
        $index++;
    }
    echo json_encode($array);
```

Then I recieve this data with $.post

```
[{
"Titel": "Begroting",
"Text": "In crisistijden mag de Vlaamse begroting in het rood gaan",
"Voor": "spa",
"Tegen": "vld",
"PuntVoor": 0,
"PuntTegen": 0
}]

$.post('../php/getFromDatabase.php', function () {}).done(function (data) {
    console.log(JSON.parse(data));
});
```

but i always get this error (about `console.log(JSON.parse(data));`)

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
>       at JSON.parse ()
>       at Object.success (script.js:20)
>       at i (jquery.min.js:2)
>       at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
>       at A (jquery.min.js:4)
>       at XMLHttpRequest. (jquery.min.js:4)

What did I do wrong to get this error?

Comment: Can you please post your JSON string?

Comment: Are you getting json response from server in ur browser console?

Comment: json is in the post now,

Comment: how can i check for json response?

Comment: You are getting valid json so no need to `parse` it, try directly `data` in your logic;

Comment: then it says (further in the code)   =  
Cannot read property 'TITEL' of undefined

Comment: i guess you might be reading wrong have you tried data[0].Titel

Comment: yes, that is the exact way I use it to read it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client is not able to identify the type of response received by the server. Specifying response type `JSON` should fix it.

```
$.post('../php/getFromDatabase.php', function () {}).done(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
}, "json");
```